# Nhibernate SchemaUpdate and SQLite

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

I have googled but haven't been able to find any information about future support for Nhibernates SchemaUpdate against SQLite?

And does anybody have any other solutions to recommend?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, what are you talking about? NHibernate 2.1.2.400 supports SchemaUpdates on SQLite pretty efficiently, and unless they were to drop SQLite support (don't count on it), you wouldn't be able to find any news, right? :D

Comment: Thats great news (for me atleast).Thanks for clarifying it for me.